# Recuperando valor na tabela pivô como propriedade de uma parte do relacionamento

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento, laravel-5

Tenho o relacionamento *manyToMany* entre `Grupos` e `Usuarios` e uma tabela pivot `grupo_usuario` que armazena as chaves e um campo extra `aprovador`, booleano, que serve para indicar se o usuário no relacionamento pode votar ou não.

Não sei como inserir o atributo `aprovador` para o usuário apenas nesse relacionamento para conseguir fazer algo do tipo:

```
$grupo->usuarios[0]->aprovador
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), você precisa adicionar `withPivot` na sua relação:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'grupo_usuario', 'grupo_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('aprovador');
```

Nesse caso para capturar o campo:

```
$grupo = App\Grupo::find(1);
foreach ($grupo->usuarios as $usuario) {
   echo $usuario->pivot->aprovador;
}
```

Comment: Você está certo Lúcio. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p = $usuario::find($id);
$grupo->p->aprovador;
```

Comment: Aqui não funcionou